# How to make an ajax with JQuery with cross site scripting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

i'm with a problem that i have to get the json from here:

> http://templodasdeusas.com.br/game/srv/game.php?srv=home

there is an option too to add callback function name like:

> http://templodasdeusas.com.br/game/srv/game.php?srv=home&callback=myFunction

that will return something like: `myFunction({'msgd':'value'})`;

i want to make um ajax request using jQuery, is that possible? i still receiving error with the normal $.ajax request, i was told that i must use jsonp or cross site scripting... how it works? someone got an exemple? tnx!!

Answer (score 5):

jQuery does this transparently for you, if you put `callback=?` in the URL. See [the API entry for `$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp).  You can basically forget about the cross-domain nature of the request.

So you might do something like this:

```
$.getJSON(
    'http://templodasdeusas.com.br/game/srv/game.php?srv=home&callback=?',
     function(data) {
         // use the response, contained in the data object, e.g.
         alert(data.msgd);
     }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

See this:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html

and this:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/