# Jquery $.getJSON is not working Chrome and Firefox but it works in IE

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm trying to use yahoo wheather api in my site thus I wrote a simple script like below:

```
<button>show</button><br />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var url='http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=2344116&u=c';
var query;
    $('button').click(function(){
        $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
        alert(json.units.temperature);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

It works IE (I'm getting the alert popup), but it doesn't work in chrome and firefox. Also, I validated JSON output;

```
{
    "units": {
        "temperature": "C",
        "speed": "km/h",
        "distance": "km",
        "pressure": "mb"
    },
    "location": {
        "location_id": "TUXX0014",
        "city": "Istanbul",
        "state_abbreviation": "*",
        "country_abbreviation": "TU",
        "elevation": 92,
        "latitude": 41.01,
        "longitude": 28.95
    },
    "wind": {
        "speed": 10,
        "direction": "NE"
    },
    "atmosphere": {
        "humidity": "34",
        "visibility": 9.99,
        "pressure": 1016,
        "rising": "steady"
    },
    "url": "http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/TUXX0014.html",
    "logo": "http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/nt/ma/ma_nws-we_1.gif",
    "astronomy": {
        "sunrise": "06:29",
        "sunset": "18:03"
    },
    "condition": {
        "text": "Fair",
        "code": "34",
        "image": "http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/34.gif",
        "temperature": 9
    },
    "forecast": [
        {
            "day": "Today",
            "condition": "Mostly Sunny",
            "high_temperature": 8,
            "low_temperature": 2
        },
        {
            "day": "Tomorrow",
            "condition": "Mostly Cloudy",
            "high_temperature": 8,
            "low_temperature": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Best Regards.

Osman.

Comment: Trying this in jsFiddle it gives me a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` failure in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that: http://jsfiddle.net/arXt2/ and my error log says:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=2344116&u=c. 
Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

What you want is `cross side scripting`. See [How to make an ajax with JQuery with cross site scripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284617/how-to-make-an-ajax-with-jquery-with-cross-site-scripting)

Comment: Seems like I need to make server side scripting to enable proxy. 
I'm working on sharepoint environment.I have added following code in page_load function but nothing happened. I'm still having issue :(
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Origin browser issue.

For more info: http://enable-cors.org/

try 
[Using the Yahoo Weather API with JSON and the script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237593/using-the-yahoo-weather-api-with-json-and-the-script-tag)

Comment: Luca thanks for your quick reply. 
I tried scripts written on Using the Yahoo Weather API with JSON and the script tag but problem still continue.
Weird thing I can parse data from twitter or flickr at similar script

Comment: Seems like I need to make server side scripting to enable proxy. 
I'm working on sharepoint environment.I have added following code in page_load function but nothing happened. I'm still having issue :(
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");